# Android 64bit terminal / rsync

Tags: android, terminal, 64-bit, rsync

I am trying to get my rooted LG G4 to rsync with my server. On the good old LG G2 it is running smoothly but the 64bit architecture throws errors at me.

I tried to come up with a solution from other sources (here and other sites) But it just goes on to the next file it cannot load correctly

The code I use is as follows:

export LD_PRELOAD=/system/lib64/libsigchain.so; export PATH=$PATH:/data/data/burrows.apps.busybox/app_busybox; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/data/data/burrows.apps.busybox/app_busybox:/vendor/lib*:/system/lib*; /data/data/burrows.apps.busybox/app_busybox/rsync -v -E --delete -s -r -t -l --partial --size-only --rsh="/data/data/burrows.apps.busybox/app_busybox/ssh -y -i /keypath/ssh.key -p10022" user@homeip:/some/folder/ /local/folder

First it was the libsigchain.so 32/64bit error

Now it is this: CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE DEPENDENCIES: "/system/lib/libsigchain.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE DEPENDENCIES: "libc.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit

Be it tasker, secure settings or terminal emulator ...

I would appreciate any suggestions.